# Python output format issue

Tags: python-3.x, formatting, output, newline

I am writing this simple Grid function that would print a image like this

```
..OO.OO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....



My code :
    grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
                ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
                ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
                ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
                ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
                ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
                ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
                ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
                ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

        newGrid=''

        j=0
        for j in range(0,len(grid[0])):
            for i in range(0,len(grid)):
                    newGrid += str(grid[i][j])

        print(newGrid)
```

I got the result I needed in the values but the format is not as expected - see below

```
..OO.OO...OOOOOOO..OOOOOOO...OOOOO.....OOO.......O....
```

I tried adding

```
newGrid += str(grid[i][j]) + "\n"
```

Also tried to use a direct print instead of a variable with "\n" - but I m sure I am missing something simple

Any pointers would be really great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for j in range(0,len(grid[0])):
    for i in range(0,len(grid)):
        newGrid += str(grid[i][j])
    newGrid += "\n"
```

This will enter a newline after every horizontal row is done

Comment: Thanks a lot _ I had this tried before but I guess the indentation was the issue and it was going for the inner for loop

Comment: yes the indentation :) something i also overlook now and then. mark the answer as solving if you can pls